# Get every nth item in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of HTML elements. I'm checking whether a previous object in the array exists like this:

```
var boxes = $('.box'); // creating the array

boxes.each(function(i){ // going through the array
    var prevBox = i>0?$(boxes[i-1]):false; // check whether a previous box exists
    if (prevBox) { } // do something
    else { } // do something else
});
```

This works well. But I would also need to check the existence of every fourth object (box) in the array, or more precisely whether an object three objects before the current one exists.

This doesn't work:

```
var prevBox = i>0?$(boxes[i-4]):false;
```

I believe using `jQuery.grep()` and checking if `(i % 4) == 0` might be the answer, but with my limited knowledge of Javascript, I don't know how to apply it to what I have now.

Anyone can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You can use the [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) in the loop to see if you are on a fourth interval.</s>

*Question was clarified.*

```
var boxes = $('.box'); // creating the array

boxes.each(function(i){
    if( i >= 3 ) {
        var prevBox = boxes.eq( i - 3 );
        var pos = prevBox.position();
        var top = pos.top;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but it doesn't quite do what I'm after. I need to get a `position().top` value from the object and add another value to it. In other `boxes[3]` needs a value from `boxes[0]`, `boxes[6]` from `boxes[3]`, `boxes[8]` from `boxes[5]` and so on.

Sorry, I'm having trouble explaining this in a simple way and thus wasn't being specific enough.

Comment: In other words, on each iteration I need to go back three steps, get a `position().top` value from the box, and use it to calculate a new value for this current box.

Comment: @hannu: Are you saying that for *each* element, you want the one that is 3 behind it? Your numbering in the comment above isn't consistent. It goes from 3 to 6 to 8. There isn't a pattern there.

Comment: ...just saw your new comment. That makes more sense. I'll update.

Comment: @hannu: Just updated. Basically you just start your look-back if `i >= 3`. If you need to do something else when `i < 3`, just add an `else` statement to the `if()`.

Comment: @patrick dw: Thank you! Works perfectly. It was a lot more simple than I thought.

Answer (score 16):

Can you not just use a for loop?

```
for ( var i=0; i< boxes.length; i+=4 )
  {
    // do stuff with boxes[i]
  }
```

I'm not big on JQuery specifically, but in regular JavaScript that would work fine.

EDIT: You've redescribed the problem somewhat, so you want to act on every item, but do something specific on the fourth...

```
var previousTop;
for ( var i=0; i< boxes.length; i++ )
  {
    // do stuff with boxes[i]
    if ( ( (i+1) % 4 ) === 0 )
      {
          previousTop = boxes[i].position.top;
          // do stuff with the fourth item
      }
  }
```

Here the more broadly scoped `previousTop` is then being set every fourth item before you do whatever else you need to do. Then when you reach the next fourth element you have the value from the previous one in your temporary variable, which sounds similar to what you are looking for from your response to @patrick dw's answer below.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to do this inside the .each() loop though since I'm doing other stuff inside it already.

Comment: Do the same and increment i by one, then rather than the anonymous function just have a few lines of code there. More transparent and easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks again! I believe this still has the same issue that @patrick dw's original solution. What I needed was in every iteration of the loop to go back three steps and get a value from there, while this gets every fourth item (0, 3, 6, 9 etc.). Sorry, just wasn't being specific enough!

Comment: Also you have to change `i+=4` to `i = i+4` in order for the first suggestion in this answer to work

Comment: @MartinCortez are you sure? Just tried it in the Javascript console on Chrome and it worked fine.

Comment: No need to do the addition `if (i % 4 === 3) {  }` will also capture every 4th item.

Comment: @AntonB But we are interested in performing an action on the third item then every fourth from there. This would not set the value correctly on a collection of length 8, 12, and so on because the condition would never trigger.

Comment: @glenatron Not sure I follow what your saying... Here is a collection of length 8 as you stated in your comment. But it indeed does get executed on the 4th position and the 8th position - which translates to every (4)nth item, just check the console... http://jsbin.com/zetoqi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Sorry, on a collection of length 7, 11, the issue would not apply correctly. The requirement in this question is a little bit quirky, which is why I used this method, but honestly I don't know if I would approach this in anything close to this way now. My JS has grown a lot.

Comment: Again check my example and read the console, it captures every (4)nth item... which was the requirement. The answer above these comments give you the same result as mine `if (i % 4 === 3) { }` regardless of the length. Regardless of its length, if its 11 length it will capture 4th and 8th item, obviously the length isnt 12 so we cant capture the 12th item. Maybe I just misunderstand your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use an iteration with 4 as the incrementing step and not the usual 1.