# get sub array of array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array in javascript and I want a sub array of the array with element which are at position n*3, n=0,1,2..  for example if:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

var subArr = [1,4,7,10]
```

Edit :  any soln without looping.

Comment: There are fancier ways but why don't you simply loop ?

Comment: And that's not a correct array literal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get every nth item in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806968/get-every-nth-item-in-array)

Comment: @FelixKling: The name seems like it applies, but the actual question is too localized to aply here.

Comment: @ColinDeClue: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4807080/218196) is applicable, but it uses a loop (which I didn't see is not desired for whatever reason).

Comment: But the question isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @ColinDeClue: Well, I cannot take back a close vote. These things happen.

Comment: You can't do this without a loop. Every solution that looks like it doesn't have a loop, really has one. It may be hidden from you, that's all. Just go with clean and simple code, whether it looks like it has a loop or not.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of a fancy way :

```
var brr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].filter(function(_,i){ return !(i%3) })
```

But a simple loop would have been as good (and would have been compatible with IE8). note that `filter`, even if it's not visible, *does* loop over the array. You can't avoid a loop (at least for an arbitrary sized array) even if you may disguise it.

---

Here's how you would do it with a standard loop :

```
var brr = [];
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=3) brr.push(arr[i])
```

Performance is rarely a concern on such operations client side but you might find important to know that the `for` loop is much faster here : http://jsperf.com/looporfilter

Comment: why do you refer to that as "fancy"? (it looks pretty spartan to me)

Comment: It's fancy in that it's not just a for loop, I suppose.

Comment: wouldn't a for loop be more complex code, like variables and function calls and stuff?

Comment: @dystroy: thanks. looks like the loop is ~50% more code, and leaves artifacts behind, yuck... judging from this, they really should start teaching map/filter before for, especially in JS.

Comment: map/filter/reduce are very useful, they often let make you more expressive code, but I'm not convinced they're better than a loop here, even if performance isn't a concern.

Comment: @dandavis: for loops are the more easily understandable device (and much more useful in different scenarios, really) so it makes much more sense to teach it first. But, yes, map/filter are useful and should be basic knowledge for JS developers.

Comment: @dystroy: since you mention performance, i've noticed map/filter in V8 are MUCH faster than they were last year. in fact, i just tested your filter version to be about twice as fast as your for version. no more map penalty?

Comment: map and filter are optimizable by a smart compiler when the function has no side effect, and V8 is good at calling functions, but I doubt the `filter` version is faster, or even as fast, as the `for` loop. Did you test the jsperf I link to ?

Comment: @dystroy: hmm. any idea why this simple race gets such different results?  http://danml.com/pub/loopvsfor.html  (click RUN)

Comment: No precise idea but I noticed the array in your sandbox environment are overloaded with additional functions, they might add a burden, and if I paste your code in another cleaner environment (for example [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ixesor/1/edit)) I have very different results. This danml.com site doesn't seem suitable for perf tests.

Comment: The filter solution is elegant, but the for loop has a built-in 3X speed advantage before you even get into the function calls, because it only touches every third array element, while filter touches them all. And the for loop doesn't have to leave artifacts behind. You put it in a function: `function pickInterval( array, interval ) { /* loop code from your answer here */ return brr; }` Now it just does what you need and doesn't leave any extraneous variables behind.

Answer (score 0):

In order to operate on a set of data of size n, m times, where m > 1, how would you avoid iteration? Really, there is no way unless you use a set of O(1) operations like this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var subarr = [];
subarr.push(arr[0]);
subarr.push(arr[3]);
subarr.push(arr[6]);
subarr.push(arr[9]);
```

Here is a structural recursion (which can be represented by a loop, and does technically loop).

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var subarr = [];
(function recur(n){
 if( n >= arr.length ) return;
 subarr.push(arr[n]);
 recur(n+3);
})(0);
```

To note: a straight for loop will always be faster. In an expansion of @dystroy's jsperf, this recursion ran slower than the for loop, but faster than the filter. http://jsperf.com/looporfilter/2

Answer (score 0):

just for kicks, i searched for a way to actually do it without a loop like the OP wanted.
without using a loop, it's tough. 
the closest i could manage gets the right numbers, but converts them to Strings instead of numbers.

```
var r=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
alert(   "".replace.call(r+",-0,-0,-0", /(\d+),\d+,?(\d+,|$)/g, "$1,")
           .replace(/(,?\-0){1,4}$/g,"")
           .split(",")    ); 
 //shows: 1,4,7,10,13
```

if you need strong numbers, it's easy, but i am not sure if adding .map(Number) after .split(",") would constitute a loop in your book, but this is the only version that actually finds the desired results without a loop.

this also only works on positive integers as coded.

again, more for fun than something i would recommend using; don't be afraid of loops...

Comment: Still has a loop. A lot of loops in fact. I see at least three loops there. You can't avoid loops, all you can do is hide them. Of course you already know that and did this as a fun exercise, and it should definitely be evaluated in that spirit! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with no loop:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
// pickInterval is a function that automatically picks every "n"
// elements from an array, starting with the first element
var subArr = pickInterval( arr, 3 );
// now subArr is [1,4,7,10]
```

Simple, isn't it? And not a loop in sight.

Ah, but you ask, "What's the catch? You haven't implemented that `pickInterval()` function, have you? I bet there's a loop in it."

And you're right. Even if we write our `pickInterval()` function using some other function that doesn't look like a loop, *that* function will have a loop in it. And if that one just calls yet another function, eventually you will find a loop.

It may be turtles all the way down, but there's a loop underneath them all.

So, to implement `pickInterval()`, we could use either approach from @dystroy's answer. We can put the loop right inside the function:

```
function pickInterval( array, interval ) {
    var result = [];
    for( var i = 0, n = array.length;  i < n;  i += 3 )
        result.push( array[i] );
    return result;
}
```

Or we can use `.filter()`:

```
function pickInterval( array, interval ) {
    return array.filter( function( _, i ){
        return !( i % 3 );
    });
}
```

Of course there's still a loop here, down inside `.filter()`. It's just been hidden from us in the very same way that `pickInterval()` hides any loop from its caller.

And that's the real point. Use `.filter()`, use a `for` loop, use whatever you want, as long as you encapsulate it inside a function. Then the inner workings of that function don't matter so much. If you like the `for` loop because it's fast and easy to understand, use that. If you like the `filter()` version because it's interesting and elegant, use that. If you later need to use it on a very large array and it's running slow, you can replace it with the `for` loop version without affecting the code that *uses* `pickInterval()`.

Whatever code you write for this or for something like it, don't put it inline. Make a function.